# Updating URL in GeoJSONLayer using ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, react

I am working on a simple node/react application that allows for the the request of data using the URL parameter in [`GeoJSONLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-geojson/index.html). The way that I set up the API I need to be able to change the url to get a new set of data. I have set up a useEffect() to load the map that has all of the map elements and have told it to listen for changes on the `treeURL`.

```
  const [treeURL, setTreeURL]  = TreeURL();
  useEffect(async()=>{
    loadMap(treeURL)
    
  },[treeURL]);
```

The TreeURL function is just a simple useState() to default to getAll which is the default way of getting all of the data back. This part is working fine the map renders with the data that is fetched.

```
const TreeURL = () => {
    const getAll = 'getAll'
    const [treeURL, setTreeUrl] = useState(getAll)
    return [treeURL, setTreeUrl]
}
```

When I go to update the data using the setTreeURL() the function runs. treeURL prints out into the console, but useEffect() is not called and the map does not update.

```
props.list.forEach((item) => {
        elements.push(
            <li class="mr-3">
                <button 
                    key={item} 
                    className="inline-block border border-blue-500 rounded py-1 px-3 bg-blue-500 text-white" 
                    onClick={()=>{
                        setTreeURL(`getByParams?CONDITION=${item}`)
                        console.log(treeURL)
                    }
                    }>{item}
                </button>
            </li>)
    })
```